# How to Encode to German in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I have an issue where I cannot encode values to proper text.

Couple of examples in array. These are should be Greek language as result:

```
['Î¦Î»Î¿Î³Î·Ï\x84Ï\x8eÎ½', 'Î£Î¿Î± Î£Ï\x84Î±Î¹ÎºÎ¯Î´Î·', 'Î\xa0Ï\x81Î¿ÎºÎ¿Ï\x80Î¯Î¿Ï\x85']
```

Python approach will be prefer, but any other approaches also will helpful.

Comment: How'd you get this [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[i.encode('latin').decode('utf8') for i in l]
```

will give:

```
['Φλογητών', 'Σοα Σταικίδη', 'Προκοπίου']
```

---

Here we first encode it to a proper encoding and then decode it back.

Comment: it is really latin-1 , not latin. but python converts it automatically